# When do I use attrs vs passing props directly with styled-components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I am a bit confused as to when I should use the attrs constructor to pass props in styled-components:

```
const Example = styled.div.attrs(props => ({
  style: {
    color: props.color
  }
}))``;
```

and when I should just pass them direcly:

```
const Example = styled.div`
    color: ${props => props.color}
`
```

I understand that the first method is changing the in-line style and the second is generating a class but **I'm unsure of the implications of these differences.**

I have seen an error in the console that says *"Over 200 classes were generated for component styled.div. Consider using the `attrs` method, together with a style object for frequently changed styles."*

But at the same time it says in the docs *"The rule of thumb is to use attrs when you want every instance of a styled component to have that prop, and pass props directly when every instance needs a different one."*

Why not just use one of these methods all the time? When should I use each one and why?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

(TL;DR at the end)

The problem is that you're reading about two separate use-cases, and assuming that they are explaining the same thing.

The Styled Components `.attrs` method is for **passing props to a styled component**. When the docs say that you should use `.attrs` "*when you want every instance of a styled component to have that prop*", they mean something like this:

```
const CheckboxInput = styled.input.attrs({ type: "checkbox" })`
   margin: 10px;
`;
```

This means that when you use `<CheckboxInput />`, it will be a checkbox by default, no need to define the prop `type="checkbox"` every time. **This is the main purpose of the `.attrs` method.**

So you understand that when you add `style` to that component's `attrs`, it's exactly the same as passing `style` as a prop to a regular, non-styled component. It just adds that style as an inline style, skipping any optimisation that styled-components might make. Inline styles aren't usually recommended because they will always be attached as an individual style to every version of that component. Example:

```
// items is some array with 100 elements
items.map(item => (
  <button style={{ background: 'blue' }} >{item.text}</button>
));
```

This would generate 100 buttons, and each button would have their own instance of the `background: blue` style.

With Styled Components, you would do this:

```
const button = styled.button`
   background: blue;
`;
```

This would generate the style only once, no matter how many buttons you have. **Because it actually generates a CSS class**.

Unfortunately, generating CSS classes isn't a lightweight operation, so if for instance you're doing animations or doing anything that changes a style frequently, it's recommended to go with inline styles instead.

**TL;DR:**

- Use styled components for static styles and dynamic styles that don't change very often;
- Use inline styles (through `.attrs`) for styles that change frequently, like for animations.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer Ricardo. It really helped me to understand this better!

Comment: So for requently changing props, is there any reason to pass `style` in through `.attrs()` vs using an inline `style` attribute?