# what is difference between '.attrs()' and 'props' in styled-components?

Tags: styled-components

```
const Input = styled.input.attrs(props => ({
  // we can define static props
  type: "text",

  // or we can define dynamic ones
  size: props.size || "1em",
}))`
  color: palevioletred;
  font-size: 1em;
  border: 2px solid palevioletred;
  border-radius: 3px;

  /* here we use the dynamically computed prop */
  margin: ${props => props.size};
  padding: ${props => props.size};
`;

render(
  <div>
    <Input placeholder="A small text input" />
    <br />
    <Input placeholder="A bigger text input" size="2em" />
  </div>
);
```

This example was taken from an official documentation

but, I think this code is same as follows:

```
const Input = styled.input`
  color: palevioletred;
  font-size: 1em;
  border: 2px solid palevioletred;
  border-radius: 3px;

  margin: ${props => props.size};
  padding: ${props => props.size};
`;

render(
  <div>
    <Input placeholder="A small text input" />
    <br />
    <Input placeholder="A bigger text input" size="2em" />
  </div>
);
```

i don't understand to difference between '.attrs()' and 'props' in styled-components

Comment: This will answer your question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60079950/when-do-i-use-attrs-vs-passing-props-directly-with-styled-components

Comment: thx bro :) have a good day

Comment: I hope that helped you. Kindly upvote the comment so others can find it useful as well. In fact I will put a link by answering it so if someone lands here they can be redirected to that post

Comment: I have put it up as an answer as well, linking to that similar question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use inline styles (via `attrs`) if there are changes or something,like animation etc.

If styles dont change very often then use styled component with static and dynamic styles

Came across this already [answered similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60079950/when-do-i-use-attrs-vs-passing-props-directly-with-styled-components). [Kindly check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60079950/when-do-i-use-attrs-vs-passing-props-directly-with-styled-components)